# Application restart state management

Tags: asp.net, session, restart

Our asp.net web application restarts randomly and kicks off users while they are filling a big batch process form.
- the users have to re logging and fill everything afresh
- so keeping in mind that the  application/session restarts randomly - which is the most appropriate technology to use for state management - session state (with MS-SQ L server) or asp.net cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure something other than InProc for your Asp.Net session state provider.  What you use depends on how durable the session data needs to be.  The session state service is fine but if it does down it will still affect your application like InProc does today.  Using a database is the most durable method, although this costs some performance.

You'll have to try and test which one is most appropriate for your needs.

You might also want to figure out why your app is crashing and fix it.  I'm assuming its not a scheduled recycle as you said it was random.  Recycling is really a Band-Aid for a badly behaving application.